# Is it possible to execute code after returning an HTTP response from WebApi?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a web service that demands the following logic:

1. Receive request
2. Log request
3. Respond that request was received
4. Process request (parse and run logic)

The reason for this is that the broker of the message doesn't want to wait on us to complete our (potentially "long running"; <10s probably <1s) logic before knowing that we've received the request.

One option I see is to simply write to the log and return, and let a timed job process the messages from the log, but that seems excessive (although we plan to implement this as a backup anyway).

My working solution is to spawn a `Task` in a Message Handler that passes on the message, but I don't know enough about threading to know what issues could arise from leaving an orphaned `Task` around. Here is this solution as described:

```
public class LoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{

    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        string content = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        HttpRequestHeaders header = request.Headers;
        HttpMethod method = request.Method;
        Uri uri = request.RequestUri;
        Version version = request.Version;
        IDictionary<string, object> properties = request.Properties;

        // Reset content. This might not be necessary, but due to the fact
        // HttpRequestMessage.Content is only meant to be read once it's
        // here to be safe.
        request.Content = new StringContent(content);

        bool messageLogged = true;
        // Write content to message table
        if (!messageLogged)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(
                System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }

#pragma warning disable CS4014 // Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        });
#pragma warning restore CS4014 // Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed

        return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Is this as terrible as it seems to me? Can `Task.Run(..)` throw an exception (Out of memory, etc?), and what would that result in? Am I going to run into issues with the thread pool?

In short, is there a proper solution to this problem?

Comment: Because you're catching the exception in Task.Run, nothing will go wrong, the only problem is see is you can be lying to whoever is requesting you because the code inside the task could have an error and you're returning OK.

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of architecture I think.

I would consider using a message queue for long running tasks. It could be a in-memory implementation in the simplest form. You can always make some logic to retry messages and update status on the message item in your log / table.

But if you want a more robust handling of messages I would prefer to use a message broker such as RabbitMQ, Azure Service Bus + many more. They provide you with message resilience and enable you to use a variety of patterns to implement how the messages will be handled.

So my suggestion would be for long running tasks:

1. Receive request
2. Log request
3. Pass the message to a message broker (for parsing and logic) - and don't wait for it.
4. Respond that request was received
5. Do something else from the client side to follow up on the message later on (events, websocket, polling ++)

Comment: I agree and suggest you to take a look at [HangFire](http://hangfire.io/), which could help you creating such an application easily.